# Access data on HDD from another computer

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a new PC with nvme and Ubuntu on it. And I have an internal hdd from an old PC with Windows and Ubuntu on it. What I need is to access data on hdd and copy some folders to nvme. Early on the old PC I was able to read data from Windows partition when being booted to Ubuntu. Now when I plug that hdd into the new PC I see no partition at all on it.

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

gives this

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EZEX-08W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

The size is correct so /dev/sda is the right disk but I see no partition to mount.

```
$ sudo lshw -short -class disk -class volume
H/W path           Device           Class          Description
==============================================================
/0/100/1d/0/0/1    /dev/nvme0n1     disk           512GB NVMe namespace
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/1                   volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/2  /dev/nvme0n1p2   volume         476GiB LVM Physical Volume
/0/b/0.0.0         /dev/sda         disk           1TB WDC WD10EZEX-08W
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo lshw -short -class disk -class volume`?

Comment: @WayneVosberg added

Comment: You are right - there does not seem to be a partition table on /dev/sda. I've never tried to recover lost partitions but you may want to start here: https://superuser.com/questions/133799/how-do-i-restore-a-partition-without-losing-the-data